# Tweak Informix query

Tags: database, informix

I have a bunch of Informix queries and I need to verify the performance of each query.

All these queries are long and contain a lot inner SELECT and JOINs. So I am wondering if there is any tool which can assist me to check which fragment in the query affects the whole query performance?

It would help a lot because it's hard to check only by eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to analyze queries then use Informix `SET EXPLAIN` and analyze output file it creates. Have a look at IBM documentation: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409fan/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX52&S_CMP=cn-a-db2